# Removing Specific Duplicates from an Excel Array

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that has a list of account numbers and their attributes.  Assume these are the only two columns on the sheet:

```
A      B
12345  Equity    
12345  Cash    
12345  Cash    
55555  Fixed Income    
55555  Cash
```

How might I remove the duplicate values that have `Cash` in column `B`, and keeping the other asset types (`Equity` for `12345` and `Fixed Income` for `55555`)?

Comment: sort on second column, select rows with "cash" and use "Remove Duplicates"

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your table with the following formula filled down (adjust ranges to match your sheet):

```
=IF(B2="Cash",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,"<>Cash")>0,"Delete","Keep"),"Keep")
```

Then, apply a filter to the table and sort by the new column Z to A. Filter for rows with value "Delete".

[image: filter steps]

Select the resulting rows, right-click them, and choose `Delete Rows`.

Then remove the filter and you should be left with what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would select the entire range, then from the Data Ribbon, choose Remove Duplicates.

In the Remove Duplicates list I would only check Column B.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to find first match of ids of column A like `MATCH(A1,A:A,0)`,
I use below formula in column `C`:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",MATCH(A1,A:A,0)))
```

That will repeat first match of an id in column `A` in column `C`,
Now use `Data\Remove Duplicates`,
And deselect column `B`.