# How can I remove the duplicate values from this excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with around 15K rows of data. I have duplicate values in this spreadsheet that consist of a combination of columns A & B. How can I remove the duplicates from this spreadsheet based on what is in column C? I would like to delete duplicates, but I would only like to delete the duplicates that have a value of 'N/A' in column C (leaving the rows that contains 'no ip proxy-arp' in column c)

```
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/1,no ip proxy-arp,Duplicate
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/1,N/A,Original
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/1.10,N/A,Original
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/1.26,N/A,Original
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/2,no ip proxy-arp,Duplicate
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/2,N/A,Original
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/2.10,no ip proxy-arp,Duplicate
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/2.10,N/A,Original
1.1.1.1,interface GigabitEthernet0/2.26,no ip proxy-arp,Duplicate
```

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/741994/76571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just happens to be in my clipboard -

```
Sub dupl()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("A1:A467")

If c.Value = c.Offset(1).Value And c.Offset(, 1).Value = c.Offset(1, 1).Value And c.Offset(1, 2) = "N/A" Then
    c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Make sure you sort column A A-Z and column B A-Z and change the range to the appropriate range.